# Form element validation using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to make a validation page and I need to stop saying "Please fill in the form" when text is entered in the text box. I only needed to validate when the text boxes are empty

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="mailto:kyletab03@gmail.com" name="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validation();" enctype="text/plain">
  Name:
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br />
  Surname:
  <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" /><br />
  Email:
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" /><br />
  Message:
  <textarea name="Message" maxlength="3500"></textarea><br />
  <button id="submit" onclick="validation()">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
  var name = $("#name").value;
  var surname = $("#surname").value;
  var email = $("#email").value;
  var comments = $("#comments").value;
  function validation() {
    if (name == "" || surname == "" || email == "" || comments == "") {
      document.myForm.name.setCustomValidity("Please fill out this field");
      document.myForm.surname.setCustomValidity("Please fill out this field");
      document.myForm.email.setCustomValidity("Please fill out this field");
      document.myForm.comments.setCustomValidity("Please fill out this field");
    } else {
      document.myForm.name.setCustomValidity();
      document.myForm.surname.setCustomValidity();
      document.myForm.email.setCustomValidity();
      document.myForm.comments.setCustomValidity();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please do not try to circumvent the title validation - if it wants a longer title, please try to do that rather than hacking it with misspellings.

Comment: Your snippet is not working.

Comment: You are trying to get the values only when page loads...not when the event occurs. Alsoa  jQuery object does not have `value` use `val()` method instead

Comment: I tried using `val()` but still the same... also how do I fix this snippet?

Answer (score 0):

your code is showing an error because in your last line you are using "comments" instead of "Message", also setCustomValidity() takes a string with the error message or an empty string and for it to work well consider using the document's methods for retrieving elements, in addition you will need to add reportValidity() so your code should look like this

```
    if (name == "" || surname == "" || email == "" || comments == "") {
    name=document.getElementById('name')
    name.setCustomValidity("Please fill out this field");
    name.reportValidity()
}
else
    name.setCustomValidity('');
    name.reportValidity()
```

also you can consider using a helper function to use the element id dynamically

Update:
 you can use this it will work

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="mailto:kyletab03@gmail.com" name="myForm" method="post" id='myform' enctype="text/plain">
  Name:
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="required"/><br />
  Surname:
  <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" required="required" /><br />
  Email:
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="required" /><br />
  Message:
  <textarea name="Message" id="message" maxlength="3500" required="required"></textarea><br />
  <button onlclick='validation()'>Submit</button>
</form>
<script>

function validate(inputID)
{
 var input = document.getElementById(inputID);
 var validityState_object = input.validity;
 if (validityState_object.valueMissing)
 {
  input.setCustomValidity('Please fill out this field');
  input.reportValidity();
 }
 else
 {
  input.setCustomValidity('');
  input.reportValidity();
 }
}
   function validation() {
   var name= document.getElementById('name').value
   var surname=document.getElementById('surname').value
   var email=document.getElementById('email').value
   var message=document.getElementById('message').value  

      validate('name') 
      validate('surname') 
      validate('email') 
      validate('message') 

 if (name!=''&&surname!=''&&email!=''&&message!='') {       
          $('#myform').submit();

    }   
}

</script>
```

Comment: What about the others, only "name" worked here, also "message" need to be required

Comment: here is the code tested and working on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sven07/09x1pvuz/#&togetherjs=THa1lrw3LQ

Comment: The previous one worked only for the name and I checked the link and turns out there is the required attributes in HTML which isn't what I want, I want to validate using jQuery

Comment: the last code works as well just make sure you add the attribute required="required" on all of the elements

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to validate forms with jquery is to use jquery validate.

I would definately advise you NOT to use mailto directly in your form post url simply because spam bots and things like that may catch hold of your form and try to use it to send spam mail. i add jquery validation and captcha on all of the contact us pages that i create for clients.

```
$('#frmsendemail').validate({ // Send Email Form
    ignore: '.ignore',
    rules: {
        seFullname: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        seContact: {
            required: true,
            phonesUK: true,
        },
        seMail: {

            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        seMsg: {
            required: true
        },
        seCaptchaStatus: {
            required: function () {
                // verify the user response

                var thisresponse = grecaptcha.getResponse(seCaptcha);
                if (thisresponse == "") {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        seFullname: {
            required: "Please Enter Your Name",
            minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please ensure you enter a name more than {0} characters long.")
        },
        seContact: {
            required: "Please Enter a contact number",
            phonesUK: "Your Contact Numer should be in the format of: 07123 456 789 or 0123 123 4567",
            minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Your contact number should me at least {0} numbers.")
        },
        seMail: {
            required: "Please Enter Your Email Address",
            email: "Your email address should be in the format of &quot;username@domain.com&quot;"
        },
        seMsg: "Please Enter A Message",
        seCaptchaStatus: "Please complete reCaptcha."
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        var id_attr = "#" + $(element).attr("id");
        $(element).closest('.pure-form-control-group').removeClass('border-success icon-valid').addClass('border-error icon-invalid');
        $(id_attr).removeClass('glyphicon-ok icon-valid').addClass('glyphicon-remove icon-invalid');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        var id_attr = "#" + $(element).attr("id");
        $(element).closest('.pure-form-control-group').removeClass('border-danger icon-valid').addClass('border-success icon-valid');
        $(id_attr).removeClass('glyphicon-remove icon-invalid').addClass('glyphicon-ok icon-valid');
    },
    showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {

        $(".seerrors").html('<h6><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>&nbsp;Your form contains ' +
            this.numberOfInvalids() +
            ' errors, see details below.</h6');
        this.defaultShowErrors();
    },
    validClass: "border-success",
    invalidClass: "border-danger",
    errorClass: "border-danger",
    errorElement: 'div',
    errorLabelContainer: ".seerrors",
    submitHandler: function () {

        //Now that all validation is satified we can send the form to the mail script.
        //Using AJAX we can send the form, get email sent and get a response and display a nice
        //message to the user saying thank you.
        //For Debugging
        //console.log("Sending Form");

        $.post("../php/sendemail.php", $('#frmsendemail').serialize(), function (result) {
            //do stuff with returned data here
            //result = $.parseJSON(result);
            console.log(result.Status);

            if (result.Status == "Error") {
                //Create message from returned data.
                //This helps the user see what went wrong.
                //If its a form error they can correct it, 
                //if not then they can see whats wrong and alert us.


                var message3 = '<p style="font-size:10pt;text-align:left !important;">We encountered an error while processing the information you requested to send.</p><p style="font-size:10px;text-align:left;">We appologise for this, details of the error are included below.<p><hr><p style="text-align:left;font-size:10px;">Error Details:' + result.Reason.toString() + '</p><pstyle="text-align:left;font-size:10px;">If this error persists, please email enquiries@cadsolutions.wales</p>';
                // Show JConfirm Dialog with error.
                $.confirm({
                    title: '<h2 style="text-align:left"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>&nbsp;We encountered an error<h2>',
                    content: message3,
                    type: 'red',
                    // Set Theme for the popup
                    theme: 'Material',
                    typeAnimated: true,
                    buttons: {
                        close: function () {}
                    }
                });
```

The above code is from a page that i created for a contact us script. the script sets all the inputs that are on the page using the name= attribute and then sets messages for the inputs when validation rules are not met, highlights and un-highlights the fields with errors, shows error messages in a set div tag and then handles form submit when the form is valid. :)